# Trying to interpolate the output of a histogram function in Python

Tags: python, numpy, scipy, interpolation, cdf

What I am trying to do is to play around with some random distribution. I don't want it to be normal. But for the time being normal is easier.

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from scipy.stats import norm

ws=norm.rvs(4.0, 1.5, size=100)
density, bins = np.histogram(ws, 50,normed=True, density=True)
unity_density = density / density.sum()

fig, ((ax1, ax2)) = plt.subplots(nrows=1, ncols=2, sharex=True, figsize=(12,6))
widths = bins[:-1] - bins[1:]

ax1.bar(bins[1:], unity_density, width=widths)
ax2.bar(bins[1:], unity_density.cumsum(), width=widths)

fig.tight_layout()
```

[image]
Then what I can do it visualize CDF in terms of points.

```
density1=unity_density.cumsum()
x=bins[:-1]
y=density1

plt.plot(x, density1, 'o')
```

[image]

So what I have been trying to do is to use the np.interp function on the output of np.histogram in order to obtain a smooth curve representing the CDF and extracting the percent points to plot them. Ideally, I need to try to do it all both manually and using ppf function from scipy.
I have always struggled with statistics as an undergraduate. I am in grad school now and try to put me through as many exercises like this as possible in order to get a deeper understanding of what is happening. I've reached a point of desperation with this task.
Thank you!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

One possibility to get smoother results is to use more samples, by using `10^5 samples` and `100 bins` I get the following images:

```py
ws = norm.rvs(loc=4.0, scale=1.5, size=100000)
density, bins = np.histogram(ws, bins=100, normed=True, density=True)
```

[image: histogram]
[image: histogram]

In general you could use [`scipys` interpolation module](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.interpolate.splrep.html#scipy.interpolate.splrep) to smooth your CDF. 
For `100 samples` and a smoothing factor of `s=0.01` I get:

```py
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from scipy.interpolate import splev, splrep

density1 = unity_density.cumsum()
x = bins[:-1]
y = density1

# Interpolation
spl = splrep(x, y, s=0.01, per=False)
x2 = np.linspace(x[0], x[-1], 200)
y2 = splev(x2, spl)

# Plotting
fig, ax = plt.subplots()
plt.plot(x, density1, 'o')
plt.plot(x2, y2, 'r-')
```

[image: CDF of Norm(loc=4, scale=1.5) interpolated]

The third possibility is to calculate the CDF analytically. If you generate the noise yourself with a `numpy` / `scipy` function most of the time there is already an implementation of the `CDF` available, otherwise you should find it on Wikipedia. If your samples come from measurements that is of course a different story.

```
import numpy as np
from scipy.stats import norm
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

fig, ax = plt.subplots()
x = np.linspace(-2, 10)
y = norm(loc=4.0, scale=1.5).cdf(x)
ax.plot(x, y, 'bo-')
```

[image: CDF of Norm(loc=4, scale=1.5) analytically]